Azure Kubernetes cluster with calico network policy doesn't block traffic for ipblock in except block of NetworkPolicy
I have an AKS cluster 1.29.2 with calico network policy. I have an egress network policy that should allow outbound traffic on internet but block all traffic in RFC_1918 range.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: egress-allow
  namespace: production
spec:
  egress:
  - ports:
    - port: 53
      protocol: UDP
    to:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          kubernetes.io/metadata.name: kube-system
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          k8s-app: kube-dns
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
        - 172.16.0.0/12
        - 10.0.0.0/8
        - 192.168.0.0/16
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: prodbindms
  policyTypes:
  - Egress

But when I am trying to connect to a svc ip of another microservice in same cluster in the same RFC_1918 range (nc -vz 172.20.217.17 8080) from prodbindms pod, it's able to connect. As soon as I remove the whole ipBlock, the connection fails but then I cant connect to any public ip as well. Basically all egress except connectivity to kube-dns starts failing.
It looks like the except in ipBlock isnt working at all. I have tried all possibilities but couldnt make this work. The same networkpolicy works fine on AWS EKS cluster. What could be the reason for this not working on Azure AKS.
AKS show details:
az aks show: "networkMode": null, "networkPlugin": "kubenet", "networkPluginMode": null, "networkPolicy": "calico",

You could back out the recent cumulative update. Or try the suggested registry value.
"After installing this update, container networking on Kubernetes might not operate as expected, preventing containers from reaching external networks or communicating between pods. It potentially impacts users setting up container networking on dev or production instances using Calico on Server 2022. Affected containers will not connect to the internet, and traffic will be blocked in host devices Firewall."
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-10-2024-kb5042881-os-build-20348-2700-5b548143-9613-4e5a-9454-8ed9be8b2bd2
